# Ruby Temperature House class

Tags: ruby

Beginner at Ruby and building a House class to read thermostat temperature. Am I on the right track and how would I call the method to update the temperature?

Let's write some code to model the behavior of a house and its thermostats. For this challenge, you should define a House class. Here is the behavior you should model:

each house has its own current temperature
each house has a method called update_temperature! which will either increase or decrease the temperature depending on if the heater or the air conditioner is on. It will also print the current temperature to the screen.
when the heater is on, the current temperature increases by 1 unit
when the air conditioner is on, the current temperature decreases by 2 units

you can turn the heater on/off
and you can turn the air conditioner on/off

As a bonus, you can add this behaviour for a smart House:

each house has its own minimum and maximum temperature
when the current_temperature reaches maximum temperature, the air conditioner turns on and the heater turns off (if it is on)
when the current_temperature reaches minimum temperature, the heater turns on and the air conditioner turns off (if it is on)
Each house should have its own state, meaning that I can create many different instances of the House class, each with their own temperature.

```
class House
  def initialize(current_temp, heater, air_cond)
    @current_temp = current_temp
    @heater = heater
    @air_cond = air_cond
  end

  def update_temperature!
    if @heater
      puts @current_temp += 1
    elsif @air_cond
      puts @current_temp -= 2
    end
  end
end

my_house = House.new(34, false, true)
my_house.update_temperature!
```

Comment: You are on the right track, and you would call it like this:  house1 = House.new(75, false, true) ; house1.update_temperature!  Though I would avoid using puts in the update_temperature, as it should really just do the action.

Comment: People are downvoting you, but your question is not stupid at all. The answer that I provided does not include the thermostat. Try to understand my code, and write the Thermostat class by yourself. The problems and questions that you will encounter will help you grow as a Rubyist. May the force be with you.

Comment: I am locking this post for a bit so it is not edited for now; I expect after it is unlocked, it will *not* be edited in this manner again. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, to call an instance method, you first have to create an instance of that class. In this case, you have a House class.

```
my_house = House.new(72, true, false)

my_house.update_temperature!
```

That being said, there are some issues with your code.

First, it's generally bad practice to use `then` in your if statements. Instead you can do something like this with replacing

```
if @heater then @current_temp += 1
```

with

```
@current_temp += 1 if @heater
```

or

```
if @heater
  @current_temp += 1
end
```

Second, I might rewrite the `update_temperature!` method to an if/else statement. I'll leave that up to you to learn.

Finally, you need to add an `end` to the initialize method so your initialize method would look like

```
   def initialize(current_temp, heater, air_cond)
     @current_temp = current_temp
     @heater = heater
     @air_cond = air_cond
   end
```

I would conclude in saying that you should check out [Why's Poignant Guide to Ruby](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/). This will help you tremendously with some some of the issues you're dealing with.

Comment: thanks for the info. Yeah there should've been an 'end' after the initialize method, not sure what happened when I copied and pasted it. See my updated code above. So if I return my_house = House.new(72, true, false) -- my_house.update_temperature! it should return 73 right? Because at the moment it is only returning 1 –

Comment: Well think about it. Your initialize method looks fine. It's assigning current temperature to 72. What about `update_temperature`? What line of code could be changing the current temperature? Look at your code. Run print on each variable to see where it might change.

Comment: OK I see now, I don't need to initialize @current_temp to 0 because it is just incrementing from 0 which is what I don't want.

Comment: Great! Make sure to check the answer that solved your question.

Answer (score 3):

You are running a simulation here. First install SY gem for physical units:

```
gem install sy
```

Then, this is how one might go around a controlled environment simulation:

```
require 'sy' # physical units
module ControlledEnvironment
  class Air
    SPECIFIC_HEAT_CAPACITY = 1.005.kJ.kg(-1).K(-1)
    attr_accessor :volume, :temperature, :humidity, :pressure, :gas_composition
    # to simplify things, let's forget about humidity, gas compositions...

    def initialize( volume: 500.m(3),
                    temperature: SY::TRIPLE_POINT_OF_WATER + 20.K,
                    pressure: 101.3.kPa )
      @volume, @temperature, @pressure = volume, temperature, pressure
    end

    def density
      density_of_air_at_0_celsius = 1.205.kg.m(-3)
      atmospheric_pressure = 101.3.kPa
      density_of_air_at_0_celsius *
        SY::TRIPLE_POINT_OF_WATER / temperature *
        pressure / atmospheric_pressure
    end

    def heat!( energy )
      @temperature += energy / ( SPECIFIC_HEAT_CAPACITY * volume * density )
    end

    def cool!( energy ); heat -energy end
  end

  class ThermalExchanger
    attr_accessor :power_output
    attr_reader :target

    def initialize( power_output, target )
      @power_output = power_output
      @target = target
    end

    def act( delta_time, pow=power_output )
      target.heat! pow * delta_time
    end
  end

  class Heater < ThermalExchanger
    def heat!( delta_time )
      act delta_time
    end
  end

  class Cooler < ThermalExchanger
    def cool!( delta_time )
      act( delta_time, -power_output )
    end
  end
end
```

Having set up a controlled environment mixin, let's make a House class using it.

```
class House
  include ControlledEnvironment # including a mixin

  # a house has air, one heater, and one cooler
  attr_reader :heater, :cooler, :air

  def initialize( heater_power: 1.kW, cooler_power: 1.kW,
                  air_volume: 500.m(3) )
    @air = Air.new volume: air_volume
    @heater = Heater.new( heater_power, @air )
    @cooler = Cooler.new( cooler_power, @air )
  end

  # its temperature is defined as air temperature
  def temperature
    "#{(air.temperature - SY::TRIPLE_POINT_OF_WATER).to_f} centigrade"
  end

  # and, given current heating / cooling power settings, we can step forward in time
  def step( delta_time=1.min )
    heater.heat! delta_time
    cooler.cool! delta_time
    puts "After #{delta_time.in( :min )} minutes, the temperature is #{temperature}"
  end
end
```

Now we can play:

```
house = House.new heater_power: 1.5.kW, cooler_power: 1.kW, air_volume: 1500.m(3)
house.temperature
#=> "20.0 centigrade"
house.step 1.h
#=> After 60 minutes, the temperature is 21.040302385090797 centigrade
house.step 1.h
#=> After 60 minutes, the temperature is 22.08429649473362 centigrade
house.heater.power_output = 0.kW # turn off the heater, for instance
#=> #<±Magnitude: 0.W >
house.step 30.min
#=> After 30 minutes, the temperature is 21.013285968306377 centigrade
100.times do house.step end
```

Comment: Quite complex for a newbie? This would be great later on for the OP, but I wouldn't recommend it to anyone who is just starting out with Ruby.

Comment: It demonstrates certain practices, how to go about real problems. With this, you can set up house insulation, you can create a thermostat object with some properties and see how well it will keep house temperature, you can later add doors, windows opening, manifest by a dramatic drop in insulation. You can include ControlledEnvironment mixin to create class Airplane, or class SpaceStation...

Comment: Yeah it is a little advanced at the moment since all I need is a simulation but it is cool to see.;)

Comment: This is what they call a simulation - reality. Just measure your house, calculate how many cubic metres it has, and this will tell you how much power you need to increase temperature by 1 centigrade in 1 hour. You can use this program when shopping for electric heaters. Or calculate contribution of your computer to your room temperature per hour. Anyway, good to see that you have Ruby 2.0 installed - in 1.9.x, those keyword arguments wouldn't run. You made a right decision to install 2.0 as a newbie, by the time you are a pro, it will be mainstream.